# Can't access dom element after append

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

I create add to cart functionality with ajax. My problem is that when I add new item to my cart, and then want to delete its, I can't. But after postbacke of page, I can remove item. I looked at questions  about my problem, but can't find solution. My codes as follow:

```
/*============ Add item to dropdown cart ========*/
$(function () {
$("a.cart").click(function () {
    var item = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/AddItemToCart",
        data: { "itemId": item },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (typeof data.thumb != "undefined") {
                // append new item to cart place
            } 
        }
    });
});
});

/*============ delete item from dropdown cart ========*/
$(function () {
$('#mainNav #cart div.cart_content ul li').find('a.remove_item').on('click',
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('li')
        .animate({ "opacity": "hide" }, "slow");
        var item = $(this).attr("id");
        var which = "shop";
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/DeleteItemFromCart",
            data: { "itemId": item, "which": which },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
              // removing this item from cart place
            }
        });
    }
);
  });
  /*======= end it =========*/
```

Comment: Any error in console? Can you also use error: callback of ajax and check

Comment: @Raunak Kathuria, thank you for reply. The click event doesn't happen, (I want to look it by firebug). As through my new dom element isn't known by jquery.

Comment: Can you post your removing or adding cart code or html that you have? Maybe it is not able to find any element with $('#mainNav #cart div.cart_content ul li').find('a.remove_item')

Comment: I look at carefully this codes, it same as others remove element. These code very large, I don't want to add/

Comment: Can you check if this is returning any element $('#mainNav #cart div.cart_content ul li').find('a.remove_item') ? if not try to change as provided in answer by Wynand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without adding more relevant code, you're reducing the likelihood of getting spot-on answers. With that in mind, I'm *guessing* that you're not attaching the same, if any, click event handler (code) to newly added items in the 'AddItemToCart' Ajax `success` callback. The only elements that will trigger the event handler are the ones that already existed in the DOM at the time when the event handler was registered, i.e. on DOM ready.

While you have the option of refactoring the code to unbind and re-attach the click event handler to all matched elements on the page (directly bound), it would be better to change it into a delegated event handler by passing a selector argument when calling [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on):

```
$('#mainNav #cart div.cart_content ul li').on('click', 'a.remove_item', function() {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Did you try by refactoring it so that the same call to `.on()` (as per your original code) is made _after_ appending any newly added element onto the page, as is currently being done on DOM ready? Or did you try with only one call to `.on()` on DOM ready, as per my suggestion? If neither works then perhaps changes to one or more other elements prevent the event handler from being called at a later stage, e.g. you could also try: `$('#cart').on('click', 'a.remove_item', function() {});` to simply and see if it makes any difference. (Again, if possible post some basic/mock-up HTML code)

Comment: your previous code doens't work, (even after postback). But second works great:D. Thank you my bro.